# jQgrid multiselect with dynamic changed cell value based on dropdown selection

Tags: jqgrid

I just found that sample

http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DataToMultiSelect2.htm

I want to have something similar:

I want to be able to post selected values on server and also i want to have a dropdown and based on that dropdown selection another cell value of that row gettign changed

How can i do that?

```
|Id|Dropdown|ValueChangedOnDropdownChanged|
 1   A[A/B]        A selected
 2   B[A/B]        B selected
```

***[A/B] it is dropdown options**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand your question correct. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DataToMultiSelect2.htm) which you reference in your question I created before for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587480/jquery-modal-dialog-and-jqgrid/3588732#3588732) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717969/jqgrid-multiselect-behavior-when-pressing-special-key/3719637#3719637).

Look at [the another old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DependendSelects3.htm). It shows how to implement dependent select (dropdown) list. The demo shows how to it in [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing), [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing) and the [searching toolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching). In case of the usage of server base data you will have to use `dataUrl` and `buildSelect` to implementation of the same behavior. The `dataUrl` should be used instead of the v property of the [searchoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config) or [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions). The `buildSelect` can be used ton only to modify the server response, but just as the good place to rebuild the dependent select (dropdown list).

Comment: i mean if each row contain some dropdown and than based on that dropdown value on the cell of current row getting changed. I add some ore details in question

Comment: @Joper: The main unclear thing for me is the context in which you needs to do it. Do you need to do it in some editing mode? If "yes" in which one (inline editing, cell editing, form editing)? The problem is that in the standard mode will be only texts displayed and **no dropdown lists**.

Comment: it will be inline editing mode by default. When user select dropdown the dropdown dependent cell(price) will be changed and than when user click submit button the rows will go to the server