# JQGrid with MultiSelect : Do not check the checkbox when clicking on rows

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jqgrid, multi-select

How to make: click on the line do not check / uncheck the checkbox,
ie, the checkbox is checked / unchecked only when you click on the column multiselect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you will find the answer on your question with the corresponding demo [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7635601/315935).