# jqGrid: using beforeSelectRow it disables my onCellSelect event

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I found a solution for my issue here:
[jqGrid multiselect - limit the selection of the row only using the checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627512/jqgrid-multiselect-box-limit-the-selection-of-the-row-only-using-the-multisele/7635601#7635601)

but that cancels out my onCellSelect event. In short, I need to be able to select the rows ONLY when the user clicks on the checkbox column. The solution in the link above shows how to do that BUT I need to be able to take an action on specific cells in the grid, for instance, the code below opens a popup window when I click on column number 10:

```
  onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e) {
      if (iCol == 10) {
          OpenPopupWindow(rowid); 
      }
  },
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should understand that both `beforeSelectRow` and `onCellSelect` are processed inside of `click` event handler which are set on the grid body (see [the part source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.5/js/grid.base.js#L2430-L2485) of jqGrid). Moreover the callback `onCellSelect` will be processed only if `beforeSelectRow` returns true so only if the row will be selected by the click (see [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.5/js/grid.base.js#L2439-L2441) of code).

What you can do as a workaround is just moving your current code of `onCellSelect` *inside* of `beforeSelectRow`:

```
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    var $self = $(this),
        iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($(e.target).closest("td")[0]),
        cm = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
    if (cm[iCol].name === "cb") {
        return true;
    }

    if (iCol === 10) {
        OpenPopupWindow(rowid);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Just small common additional remarks. I would recommend you to change testing for column number to testing for the name of the column: `cm[iCol].name === 'myColumnName'` instead of `iCol === 10`. It will make the code more maintainable. Additionally I would recommend you to change the name of function `OpenPopupWindow` to `openPopupWindow`. The naming conversion of JavaScript require that one uses function with the first capital name only for constructors. If you choose the name of the function as `OpenPopupWindow` then you gives the tip to use it with `new` operator: `var test = new OpenPopupWindow(rowid);`. You see that even the color of `OpenPopupWindow` on stackoverflow is another as the color of `$.jgrid.getCellIndex`. Your current choice looks the same like the statement:

```
var theVariableHoldOnlyIntegerValues = true; // assign boolean
```

Renaming the function `OpenPopupWindow` to `openPopupWindow` bring the colors in order.

Comment: I edited the code just for simplicity. I am using column names. Thank you so much for the detail explanation. That was great info!

Comment: @Max: You are welcome! I'm glad that you didn't taken umbrage because of my remarks about the names. Holding name conversion is really important. I am myself had the same problems because I came from C/C++/C#.