# How to add a new column of buttons/images in jqgrid

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, button, jqgrid

I am using JQgrid in ASP.net  MVC web application .

I was able to add a new columns of buttons named edit by using `formatters`

But, the problem is i was not able to get the value of a column in a row for which the button is clicked.

For example, if i click button edit ( new added) on 4th row, i would require to fetch the value of first column of that particular row.

i need this beacuse i want to redirect to another page with that value and do the edit there.

I was not able to fetch that value and add javascript to it.

Please help on this with any code samples..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to bind `click` event handler to *every* button in the column. Every binding take memory and other resources of web browser. The most events bubbling to from inner to outer DOM element (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Event_flow)), Mouse click, Keyboard keydown, Touch touchstart and other events on the button inside of grid will be bubble to the grid's `<table>` element. jqGrid register by default `click` event handler on the grid. It calls `beforeSelectRow` and `onCellSelect` callbacks and trigger `jqGridBeforeSelectRow` and `jqGridCellSelect` events from the event handler. So instead of binding your own `click` event handlers on every button it's enough to use one from listed above callbacks or events. `beforeSelectRow` (or `jqGridBeforeSelectRow`) will be used first. The callback is practical if you what that click on the button don't select the corresponding row. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16241558/315935) for example shows how to verify whether the column which you needs are called. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537512/315935) provides an example which will be very close to what you need. [One more answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765086/315935) gives you another code fragment. To see more my old answers about the subject you can use [the following query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:315935%20%5Bjqgrid%5D%20%2bonCellSelect%20%2bbeforeSelectRow%20).

**UPDATED**: the demo http://jsfiddle.net/ShKDX/82/ is modification of the demo posted by Manuel van Rijn. It demonstrates what I mean.

Comment: @Oleg..I really have no words after seeing your answer. Its more than 100% of what i needed..i have implemented it and working great :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's an simple example how you could add buttons dynamically to a jqgrid

http://jsfiddle.net/ShKDX/1/

Not sure if you first row is the id as specified in the fiddle, but you can modify it to use the correct data from the `afterInsertRow` function

```
var data = [
    {id: 1, text: 'row1'},
    {id: 2, text: 'row2'},
    {id: 3, text: 'row3'},
    {id: 4, text: 'row4'},
    {id: 5, text: 'row5'},
];
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    height: 250,
    colNames: ['Id', 'Text', 'edit'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'id', index: 'id', sorttype: "int" },
        { name: 'text', index: 'text' },
        { name: 'edit', index: 'edit', align: 'center', sortable: false, width: '40px' }
    ],
    caption: "Custom buttons",
    data: data,
    afterInsertRow: function(id, currentData, jsondata) {
        var button = "<a class='gridbutton' data-id='"+id+"' href='#'>edit</a>";
        $(this).setCell(id, "edit", button);
    },
    loadComplete: function(data) {
        $(".gridbutton").on('click', function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           alert('Edit id: ' + $(this).data("id"));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: @Manuel..Thanks.i will not be able to access jsFiddle..can you please put code on this page itself..

Comment: @ManuelvanRijn: I could find occasionally the old answer. I added http://jsfiddle.net/ShKDX/82/ which is modification of your demo and which shows what I mean in my answer.