# How to Pass the JQGrid Cell Value to Jquery Function using Link Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, href

My JQGrid cloumns like,

```
    colNames: ['Job ID', 'MailId','Save'],
    colModel: [
                { name: 'JobId', index: 'JobId', width: 120, align: 'left', editable: true },
                { name: 'MailId', index: 'MailId', width: 150, align: 'left', editable: true },

                {
                    name: 'Save', index: 'Save', width: 100, sortable: false,
                    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                        return "<a href='#' id="saveLinkId">Save</a>";

                    }
                }
```

I create the Save link button at the end of JQGrid cell.

I need to pass clicked row's **JobId and MailID to jquery function** when click the link button in a row.How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In the above example you have given, the rowObject parameter in the formatter function will hold all the values in that row. So can use **rowObject.JobId** for your JobId and **rowObject.MailId** for your MailId.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `beforeSelectRow` (or `onCellSelect`) to detect click on `<a>` in the `"Save"` column. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16241558/315935) explains what you can do. Another answers: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537512/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765086/315935) could be also interesting for you.

In your case `beforeSelectRow` could looks like below

```js
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    var $self = $(this),
        iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($(e.target).closest("td")[0]),
        cm = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
    if (cm[iCol].name !== "Save") {
        return true;
    }

    alert ($self.jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "JobId"));
    return false;
}
```

Additionally you should consider which value you use as `id` in the input data. The value build so name rowid - the value of `id` attributes of `<tr>` elements (the rows of the grid). If for example either `JobId` or `MailId` (one from the two columns) contains **unique** values for every row then you can use the value from the column as the rowid. To do this you need just add `key: true` to the corresponding column.