# showing a modal popup when a user clicks on a link jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

```
    {
        name: 'EmployeeInformation',
        index: 'EmployeeInformation',
        width: 15,
        sortable: true,
        editable: false,
        formatter: 'showlink',
        formatoptions: {
            //show an modal popup
        }
    }
```

This is a table column in my jqgrid.

What I want is when i click the link button (EmployeeInformation) it will show a modal popup.

Comment: Code is useless without knowing which modal plug-in you're in

Comment: thats because i dont have any modal plug-in yet. Can you enlighten me? Zee Tee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way will be to use `formatter: 'dynamicLink'` instead of `formatter: 'showlink'` which I introduced in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9048483/315935). It allows you to define `onClick` callback (`formatoptions: {onClick: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, cellText, e) {alert('clicked in rowId=' + rowId + ', iRow=' + iRow + ', iCol=' + iCol);}}`) like in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DynamicLink.htm).  See [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins/blob/master/jQuery.jqGrid.dynamicLink.js) too.

One more way will be to define just `<span>` with `text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;` style instead of `<a>` and to use `beforeSelectRow` or `onCellSelect` to detect the click in the column to show the corresponding modal popup. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537512/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765086/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16241558/315935) and other for the corresponding code examples.