# jqgrid multiselect only use multiselect box

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, webforms, multi-select

I want  selection of the row only using  multiselect box not by click on the row.I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627512/jqgrid-multiselect-box-limit-the-selection-of-the-row-only-using-the-multisele/7635601#7635601) but onSelectRow not fired.In my app when click on row,some data show(master and details struct)
but because onSelectRow not fired.
I want select row by click and show data but check box set only click on box.Please help me :(

```
 grid.jqGrid({
            url: 'jqGridHandler.ashx',
            datatype: 'json',
            width: $("#parentDiv").width(),
            height: a,
            direction: "rtl",
            colNames: ['Action', 'A', 'W', 'Date', 'Num', 'Sender', 'F', 'EOSysNum', 'PctIndNum', 'Subject', 'PctAssignSubject', 'PctAssignType', '', 'Date2', 'Assign', '', 'PctTabName', 'Andicator', '', 'Datetime of Show', 'SysCode', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '','','','','','','','','',''],
            colModel: [
                {
                    name: 'act',
                    width: ($.browser.webkit ? 25 : 25),
                    align: 'center',
                    sortable: false,
                    formatter: 'actions',
                    formatoptions: {
                        keys: true,
                        delOptions: myDelOptions,
                        delbutton: false,
                        editbutton: false
                    }
                },
                {
                    name: 'IsAttach',
                    width: 5,
                    sortable: false,
                    search: false,
                    template: ActionTemplate,
                    formatter: function (cellval, opts, rowObject, action) {

                        return (cellval == 'True' ? "<span  class='ui-icon icon-Attachment' style='float:left'></span>" : "");
                    }
                },
                {
                    name: 'IsContent',
                    width: 6,
                    sortable: false,
                    search: false,
                    template: ActionTemplate,
                    formatter: function (cellval, opts, rowObject, action) {
                        return (cellval == 'True' ? "<span class='ui-icon icon-Word' style='float:left'></span>" : "");
                    }
                },
                {
                    name: 'PctLettDate',
                    width: 30,
                    sortable: true,
                    template: CenterTemplate,
                  //  formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                        //return (rowObject["PctViewDate"] == '' ? '<font  style="font-weight:bold">' + cellvalue + '</font>' : cellvalue)
                       // return (rowObject["PctViewDate"] == '' ? '<font  style="font-weight:bold">' + cellvalue + '</font>' : cellvalue);
                    //}
                },
                {
                    name: 'PctLettNum',
                    width: 30,
                    sortable: true,
                   // template: numberTemplate,
                   // formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                       // return (rowObject["PctViewDate"] == '' ? '<font  style="font-weight:bold">' + cellvalue + '</font>' : cellvalue);
                   // }
                },
                {
                    name: 'PctAssignPrs',
                    width: 80,
                    sortable: true,
                   // formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                     //   return (rowObject["PctViewDate"] == '' ? '<font  style="font-weight:bold">' + cellvalue + '</font>' : cellvalue)
                    //}
                },
                {
                    name: 'PctAssignImi',
                    width: 15,
                    sortable: true,
                    template: CenterTemplate,
                  //  formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                     //   return (rowObject["PctViewDate"] == '' ? '<font  style="font-weight:bold">' + cellvalue + '</font>' : cellvalue)
                    //}
                },
                { name: 'EOSysNum', width: 30, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctIndNum', width: 140, sortable: false, hidden: true },
                {
                    name: 'PctLettSubject',
                    width: 140,
                    sortable: true,
                   // formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                        //return (rowObject["PctViewDate"] == '' ? '<font size="3" color="#0072C6" style="font-weight:bold">' + cellvalue + '</font>' : cellvalue)
                    //}
                },
                { name: 'PctAssignSubject', width: 100, sortable: false, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctAssignType', width: 100, sortable: false, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctType', width: 100, sortable: false, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctStartDate', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctRecDate', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctAssignDate', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctAssignTime', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctTabName', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctIndCode', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctViewDate', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctViewTime', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'SysCode', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctIsTerminate', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctIsConfirm', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctAssignerSysNum', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'pctAssignmentNum', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctAssignPrivate', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctIsInFolder', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctAssignPhysics', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctConfirmRecLettPhysics', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'pctAssignmentPhysicsNum', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctDeputyEOSysNum', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctDeputySysCode', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctRequestStatus', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctIsTerminateByAssign', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctPosSysCode', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctAssignerPosSysCode', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'PctTabName1', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'HasAccessAssignLetter', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'HasAccessContentLetter', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'HasAccessAttachLetter', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'HasAccessCCLetter', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'HasAccessPhysicsLetter', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'HasAccessFoldersLetter', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'HasAccessDocRelatedLetter', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'HasAccessTreeLetter', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'HasAccessEmailLetter', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'AssignedPerson', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true }
            ],
            rowNum: 20,
            loadonce: true,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20],
            recordpos: "left",
            ignoreCase: true,
            toppager: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            multiselect: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            scrollOffset: 1,
            editurl: 'clientArray',
          multiboxonly: true,
            jsonReader:
            {
                repeatitems: false,
            },
            gridview: true,
            rowattr: function (rd) {

                return { "class": (rd["PctViewDate"] == '') ? "myRowClassNoRead" : "myRowClass" };

            },
            ondblClickRow: function (id) {

                $(this).jqGrid('editRow', id, true, null, null, 'clientArray');
            },
            onSelectRow: function (id) {
                rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(id);
                window.selectedRow = id,
                doShowInformationOfSelectedRow(rowData, window.activeTab);
                if (id && id !== lastSel) {
                    if (typeof lastSel !== "undefined") {
                        $(this).jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSel);
                    }
                    lastSel = id;
                }
            },
            beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) {
                var cbsdis = $("tr#" + rowid + ".jqgrow > td > input.cbox:disabled", grid);
                if (cbsdis.length === 0) {
                i = grid.getCellIndex($(e.target).closest('td')[0]),
                cm = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
                return (cm[i].name === 'cb');
                    return true;    // allow select the row
                } else {
                    return false;   // not allow select the row
                }

            },
            onSelectAll: function(aRowids, status) {
                if (status) {
                    // uncheck "protected" rows
                    var cbs = $("tr.jqgrow > td > input.cbox:disabled", grid[0]);
                    cbs.removeAttr("checked");

                    //modify the selarrrow parameter
                    //grid[0].p.selarrrow = grid.find("tr.jqgrow:has(td > input.cbox:checked)")
                        //.map(function() { return this.id; }) // convert to set of ids
                        //.get(); // convert to instance of Array
                }
            },

            loadComplete: function () {

                $('#navGridfrom').datepicker({
                    isRTL: true,
                    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                        $('#navGridto').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new JalaliDate(inst['selectedYear'], inst['selectedMonth'], inst['selectedDay']));
                    }
                });
                $("#navGridto").datepicker();
                var iCol = getColumnIndexByName(grid, 'act');
                var iColhasAccessAssignLetterIndex = getColumnIndexByName(grid, 'HasAccessAssignLetter');
                var iColhasAccessFoldersLetterIndex = getColumnIndexByName(grid, 'HasAccessFoldersLetter');
                $(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow>td:nth-child(" + (iCol + 1) + ")")
                    .each(function () {
                        var valueAccessAssignLetter = this.parentElement.cells[iColhasAccessAssignLetterIndex].innerHTML;
                        var valueAccessFoldersLetter = this.parentElement.cells[iColhasAccessFoldersLetterIndex].innerHTML;
                        $(this.parentElement).find("td > input.cbox").attr("disabled",(valueAccessFoldersLetter=="False"? true:false));
                        $("<div>", {
                                title: "Archive",
                                mouseover: function () {
                                    $(this).addClass(valueAccessFoldersLetter == "True" ? 'ui-state-hover':'');
                                },
                                mouseout: function () {
                                    $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
                                },
                                click: function (e) {
                                    if (valueAccessFoldersLetter == "True") {
                                        alert("'Custom' button is clicked in the rowis=" +
                                            $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id") + " !");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ).css({ "margin-right": "5px", "float": "left", "cursor": "pointer" })
                            .addClass(valueAccessFoldersLetter == "True" ? "ui-pg-div ui-inline-custom":"")
                            .append(valueAccessFoldersLetter == "True" ? '<span class="ui-icon icon-archive "></span>' : '<span class="ui-icon icon-archive ui-state-disabled">')
                            .prependTo($(this).children("div"));

                        $("<div>", {
                                title: "Assign",
                                mouseover: function () {
                                    $(this).addClass(valueAccessAssignLetter == "True" ?'ui-state-hover':'');
                                },
                                mouseout: function () {
                                    $(this).removeClass(valueAccessAssignLetter == "True" ?'ui-state-hover':'');
                                },
                                click: function(e) {
                                    if (valueAccessAssignLetter == "True") {
                                        alert("'Custom' button is clicked in the rowis=" +
                                            $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id") + " !");
                                    }
                                }                                    
                            }
                        ).css({ "margin-right": "10px", "float": "left", cursor: "pointer" })
                            //.addClass("ui-pg-div ui-inline-custom")
                            .append(valueAccessAssignLetter == "True" ? '<span  class="ui-icon icon-refrence" disabled></span>' : '<span class="ui-icon icon-refrence ui-state-disabled"></span>')
                            .prependTo($(this).children("div"));
                    });
                $("tr.jqgrow", this).contextMenu('myMenu1', {
                    direction: 'rtl',
                    bindings: {
                        'edit': function (trigger) {
                            // trigger is the DOM element ("tr.jqgrow") which are triggered
                            grid.editGridRow(trigger.id, editSettings);
                        },
                        'add': function (/*trigger*/) {
                            grid.editGridRow("new", addSettings);
                        },
                        'del': function (trigger) {
                            if ($('#del').hasClass('ui-state-disabled') === false) {
                                // disabled item can do be choosed
                                grid.delGridRow(trigger.id, delSettings);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    onContextMenu: function (event/*, menu*/) {
                        var rowId = $(event.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");
                        //grid.setSelection(rowId);
                        // disable menu for rows with even rowids
                        $('#del').attr("disabled", Number(rowId) % 2 === 0);
                        if (Number(rowId) % 2 === 0) {
                            $('#del').attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        } else {
                            $('#del').removeAttr("disabled").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            },
```

Comment: My [old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7635601/315935) which you referenced uses `beforeSelectRow` instead of `onSelectRow`. Is `beforeSelectRow` not fired in your grid? Could you provide a code which demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer :).beforeSelectRow is fire but  onSelectRow not fire.in onSelectRow show data base on row selecected.I edit my question and add some code

Comment: If `beforeSelectRow` ends with `return false` then no selection of the row take place and `onSelectRow` not fire. Moreover I don't see why you need use both `beforeSelectRow` and `onSelectRow`.

Comment: I use onSelectRow for show data base on selected row and use beforeSelectRow for when some of rows should not select by multielect box(disable multielect box of row base on condition)

Comment: For disable of multiselect box i use  [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259262/jqgrid-multiselect-and-disable-check-conditional)

Comment: I still don't understand why you can't move the code on `onSelectRow` inside of `beforeSelectRow`? You current code seems me strange because of many reasons. For example `loadComplete` contains code which do something in columns `act` and `iCol2` which are not defined in `colModel`, you set boolean value of `"disabled"` attribute instead of setting string `"disabled"`. You examine **HTML** code of column and it's not clear how the code come in grid. If you place HTML fragments in grid data some selects of rows will not been done.

Comment: [The answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259262/jqgrid-multiselect-and-disable-check-conditional) is more as 2 years old. I fixed value of `"disabled"` attribute in the answer. Other my questions are still opened. I think that you should better use `beforeSelectRow` instead of `onSelectRow` in your case.

Comment: Sorry,i put a short code i edit my question again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirement

> I want select row by click and show data but check box set only click on box

contradicts with the meaning of `multiselect: true` option in jqGrid. You can change behavior of selection. For example you can select rows by click on multiselect checkbox only. What you want is **selection of rows without checking of multiselect checkbox**. The requirement contradicts with the meaning of `multiselect: true` option.

If you need some chechboxes in your grid which will be checked based on your custom algorithm you can include column with `formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false }`.

I recommend you to move code from your `onSelectRow` callback inside of `beforeSelectRow` callback.

Additionally I would recommend you to reduce the number of hidden columns which you use. It I calculated correctly you have 40 (!!!) hidden columns and only 8 visible columns in the grid. Every hidden column take place on DOM of the page and makes working with the grid slowly. What you need is just having object with all properties which represent the row. Usage of JavaScript variables is much quickly for the purpose as the usage of hidden columns. One can do this in many way. For example one can fill `userdata` inside of `beforeProcessing` with full data which represent the items in almost the same way like in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14205263/315935).

**UPDATED**: If for example you use `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }` and the column `syscode` contains unique id of you data then you should

1. include `key: true` property in definition of the `syscode` column or use `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, id: "syscode" }`. I recommend to make both.
2. include `beforeProcessing` callback which fill `userdata` property in the server response. For example

```js
beforeProcessing: function (data) {
    var rows = data.rows, l = rows.length, i, item, itemBySysCode = {};
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        item = rows[i];
        if (item.syscode) {
            itemBySysCode[item.syscode] = item;
        }
    }
    data.userdata = itemBySysCode;
}
```

Now you can access remove all hidden rows from `colModel` and `colNames`. If you need *full item object* you should don't use `getRowData` method now (`jQuery(this).getRowData(id)`). The method you could use to get **non-hidden properties** only. To access hidden properties you can use `$(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "userData")[id]`. In the case `userData` will get you *original data* loaded from the server and `jQuery(this).getRowData(id)` or `$(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "data")` will get you current data after modification (your code contains local editing of data).

Comment: For reduce the number of hidden columns i can remove columns and use beforeProcessing (according to example) for save data in JavaScript variables(for example userdata).Do i understand correctly?

Comment: @ZSH: Exactly! You will have the grid with 8 columns only and use something like `jQuery(this).getGridParam("userData")[id]` instead of `jQuery(this).getRowData(id)`. I wanted to post you code example, but it was not clear how you specify `id` in your data. You don't use `key: true` for some column. Do you have additional `id` property in every item of data returned from the server? Could you include an example of data (2 rows) returned from the server?

Comment: Column 'syscode' is key and i use default key(row number).I  set key to true for syscode.I fill 'userData' and jQuery(this).getGridParam("userData") its work but jQuery(this).getRowData(id) not work i also add syscode into userData

Comment: @ZSH: See **UPDATED** part of the answer for the code example.